# SQL: different results when using wildcard?

Tags: sql, postgresql

*Using PostgreSQL 9.6.12.*

Given an author has many blog posts.

When I run the following query I get a row for each associated post.

```
SELECT authors.id
FROM authors
LEFT JOIN posts ON authors.id = posts.author_id
```

When I run the following, I only get a row for each author:

```
SELECT authors.*
FROM authors
LEFT JOIN posts ON authors.id = posts.author_id
```

When I run a count on either one, however, I get the higher row count. E.g. the count of all the posts.

Why don't I get the higher row count result when I use the wildcard to select all the columns?

Comment: the wildcard is just for not writing all the fields that are selectable, it does not mean anything else. Both query return the same rows

Comment: Neither of these queries returns the cartesian product of the 2 tables.

Comment: the number of rows  returned  by the two queries is the same  ..

Comment: Those are NOT cartesian products.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm seeing different row number results in PSQL when I run these two queries. Maybe it's not a cartesian product, but the visible row counts are not the same at all.

Comment: Even considering your question is not well written, we can still help you if you add sample data and expected results. A few rows of data will go a long way to help us seeing the problem.

Comment: I've updated the question to avoid the word "cartesian" because I may not understand that correctly.

Comment: Oh dear, I took the time to respond now that you have modified the question.

Comment: Does this change if you run `reindex authors;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be caused by how you are running the query, and the settings of the IDE. These queries should return the same row count. Please run the following queries to check.

```
select count(*) from (SELECT authors.id
FROM authors
LEFT JOIN posts ON authors.id = posts.author_id)

select count(*) from (SELECT authors.*
FROM authors
LEFT JOIN posts ON authors.id = posts.author_id)
```

Comment: Well spotted. I'm using a new GUI and it truncated the results. When I scroll further down in psql I see the remaining results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Why don't I get a cartesian product result when I use the wildcard to
>   select all the columns?

**You do not get a cartesian product in either of the two SQL queries.**

> When I run a count on either one, however, I get the cartesian product
>   number of rows. E.g. the count of all the posts.

**You are not calculating the count of all the posts.** You are retrieving all posts that have an author in the `authors` table.

---

I am afraid you are confusing the term cartesian product. A cartesian product is the number of rows in the first table times the number of rows in the second table, without and limiting clause/condition. In simple SQL it would correspond to the following e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM authors, posts
```

The two queries in your question return the exact same rows, except that the first query displays only the column `id` of the `authors` table while the second displays all the columns of the `authors` table.

This is standard SQL and I am very confident that every technology respecting the SQL standard would respect the above said.

I hope you see what I mean and suggest that you review the question. It may help if you can show some concrete example, in particular you would have to clarify:

- what do you mean by "cartesian product"? (your definition differs from the common usage)
- how do you count rows? (according to your example I find it hard to believe you count different number of rows; they must be equal)

Comment: thanks for your response. It came just after I edited the question to drop the term "cartesian product". I'm just counting rows visually. Using `count` returns the same value for both.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. If you count rows visually may the application you use the execute the query has some specific behaviour in displaying data. E.g. when I use SQL Developer it displays the first 50 rows; the rest of the rows is displays gradually on demand when I scroll to the end of the result list. Does that make sense that your app has a specific behaviour too? Which tool do you use to execute the SQL queries ?

Comment: I'm seeing this with postbird and psql (both on Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: Unfortunately I am not acquainted with postbird or psql. If you run Ravishankar's test and you see the same row count you can rest assured - it is a tool specific behaviour, you are likely seeing just what the tool decided to display. The results are still correct.

Comment: thanks so much for your patience and help, despite my misuse of that term. This was indeed a tool related issue. When I scroll further down in psql I see the remaining rows as expected, but not in the GUI.

Comment: No worries, all is well.